# count number of rows in excel using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

i have the excel sheet with code like

```
VPUDB001
VPUDB002
VPUDB003
VPUDB004
VPUDB005
VPUDB006
VPUDB007
VPUDB008
VPUDB009
VPUDB010
VPUDB011

VPULN001
VPULN002
VPULN003
VPULN004
VPULN005
VPULN006
VPULN007
VPULN008
VPULN009
```

I want to display the number of rows starting with `VPUDB` and `VPULN` in excel.

```
private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult fileopen = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    textBox1.Text = filename;
    try
    {
        olecon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + filename + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0");
        olecon.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = olecon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string[] excelsheetnames = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            excelsheetnames[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            string sheetnamealone = excelsheetnames[i].Remove(excelsheetnames[i].IndexOf('$'));
            comboBox1.Items.Add(sheetnamealone);
            i++;
        }
        //comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;

    }
    catch
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        olecon.Close();
    }
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [code] FROM ["+comboBox1.SelectedItem+"$] ", olecon);
    olecon.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dReader.Read())
    {
        string s = dReader[0].ToString();


    }
    olecon.Close();
}
```

Here i browse the excel sheet and i count and display in combo box, then in combo selected event i need to count the particular sheet rows as said above.

Comment: Why not use `COUNTIF()` worksheet function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try linq like this will resolve your issue

```
 var query = from row in dTable.AsEnumerable()
             where ((row.Field<string>("columnname")).contains("VPUDB")
                   || (row.Field<string>("columnname")).contains("VPULN"))

      select row;
```

Comment: but sir, my id will get change dynamically, its not static..it may be AAAAB or something else

Comment: hi, Pranay Rana, i used the following string[] strarray = strlst.ToArray();

                var distinctValues = (from value in strarray select value).Distinct();
                //or even better
                distinctValues = strarray.Distinct(); i used the disctint code, i need disctint code along with count... can u help in this

Comment: @chitra - you can use Count() function for that ...........soemthing like distinctValues = strarray.Distinct(); and int count = distinctValues.Count();

Comment: hi, Pranay Rana, count=distinctvalues.count() gives me the value 2. I want to display like VPUDB-12, and VPULN-10. I mean the number of times the values repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a string comparison to see if it contains `VPUDB` or `VPULN` when you are initially counting for your combobox, and if it does, increment a counter.

Comment: but i have different combination of list...it not containing particular word

Comment: You can use something like this:

if(string contains VPUDB) 

add to list A

else if(string contains VPULN)

add to list B

Comment: Mac-thanks for replying me, my code is dynamic, it will have different combination. it may SFTEG, ect. I want to select the first 5 character from string array and compare it with next row, if it same the count, then the next combination and i want to display VPUDB-20,VPULN-35,SFTEG-12.

Comment: OK, if that is what you require it to do, then just read a cell, read the next and compare. If its the same, then increment a counter according to the text that is within the cell. This program's requirement is a simple text comparison...