# How to use getstring in datareader in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to select 1st 5 character and assign in stringarray, i tried the following code, but it showing me error. I want to select first 5 character of each row and assign to str. Suggest me some idea plz.

```
public string[] str;
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    str = dr[0].GetString(4).tostring();
}
```

Comment: check answer will work for you.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make use of SubString function that will do that task for you

full code

```
List<string> strlst = new List<string>();
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    strlst.Add( Convert.ToString(dr[0]).Substring(0, 5)) ;
}
string[] strarray = strlst.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank u, its getting. Sorry to ask 1 more question here, i want to count each group in that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560297/count-number-of-rows-in-excel-using-c-sharp

Comment: @chitra _ welcome..I answered your question if this solution worked for you do accept answer and upvote it.........