# How to dynamically generate labels which displays values in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, label, dynamically-generated

I want to display the values in a dictionary in separate labels. I get the dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (string code in myCodeList)
{
    if (!counts.ContainsKey(code))
    {
       counts.Add(code, 1);
    }
    else
    {
       counts[code]++;
    }
}

//now counts contains the expected values
```

I want to generate labels dynamically since elements in `counts` can only be determined at runtime.

Comment: I don't get your code, why not just Label.Text=String.Concat(",",myList);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, int> counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (string code in myCodeList)
{
    if (!counts.ContainsKey(code))
    {
       counts.Add(code, 1);
    }
    else
    {
       counts[code]++;
    }
}

Point p = new Point(12, 12); //initial location - adjust it suitably
foreach (var item in counts)
{
    var label = new Label();
    label.Text = item.Key + " - " + item.Value;
    label.Location = new Point(p.X, p.Y);
    label.Tag = item; //optional
    Controls.Add(label);

    p.Y += label.Height + 6; //to align vertically
    //p.X += label.Width + 18; //to align horizontally. 
}
```

This is the basic approach. All you have to do is adjust the variable `p` according to your design to locate the labels properly.

Comment: hi, nawfal,thank u, so i want to display in separate label VPUDB - 11 and VPULN - 9, i need it in dynamically, suppose it may contain 3 or 4 labels also.

Comment: @chitra do you want those values to be listed in one label or you want each string to be displayed in separate labels?

Comment: separate label, but label should be dynamics, suppose, my string array may contain 3 or 4 codes...depends on my string input

Comment: @so you mean if there are 4 strings in string array, then you need those 4 strings to be displayed in 4 separate labels?

Comment: sorry, S, if it 4 means 4 label

Comment: @chitra, what u r trying to achieve is pretty trivial, but that wasn't clear at all from your question. So you have some strings basically in an array. Now which is that array from your question? `myList` or `counts`? What are you trying to achieve in that foreach loop?

Comment: read my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560297/count-number-of-rows-in-excel-using-c-sharp/11591390#11591390. i randomly choose one excel sheet which contains code, i want to count the group of code and display it in label.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14265/discussion-between-nawfal-and-chitra)

Answer (score 0):

This should be suffice

**EDIT**

```
YourLabel.Text = counts.Count.ToString();
```